# how to make automatic box-shadow changing color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found some code, that change box-shadow color on every mouse hover, and I can't to make it change. i'm trying setInterval, but this doesn't help.

Can someone have an idea how to make it ?

```js
$('#random').on('mouseover',function() {
    var color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    var colorString = '0px 0px 30px 0px ' + color;
    $('#random').css('box-shadow',colorString);
    $('#random').css('-webkit-box-shadow',colorString);
    $('#random').css('-mox-box-shadow',colorString);
});
```

```css
#random {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="random">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? I just ran this in a fiddle and it works fine.

Comment: please include jquery in your code https://jsfiddle.net/0n12sos2/

Comment: Works for me.  Have you included a reference to jQuery?  Put `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>` in the `<head>` section.

Answer (score 0):

I see the following error in the console:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

This means you might have not included the jQuery in your HTML

I used your code with jquery and is working fine.

https://jsbin.com/pekociribu/edit?html,css,js,output